# excel 2010 add-in setup project with setup factory

Tags: excel, installation, excel-2010, excel-addins

I am developing an excel add-in. I have serial numbers(ex. 100 psc) and I want to check when excel add-in installing on pc. But I cant do it with VS2010 setup project because it is not supporting serial number list storing and checking.

so I want to do this with setup factory and I did it like this link:
[link](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/AddinsAndSetupFactory.asp?AllComments=True)

but I have a problem excel ;
[image]

if I select "Yes", excel working for opening .dll, if select "No", it do anything.

[image]

and my setup factory list like this.
[image]

and my setup factory "on post install script", my Addinfilename value is "Posta Guvercini Excel AddIn For 2010.dll"

```
    -- Determine registry key (2 = HK CURRENT USER)
sVersions = Registry.GetKeyNames(2, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office");

-- Iterate through the registry keys per MS Office-version
--Next line has SetupFactory 8 code
--for iCount1, sVersion in sVersions do    
for iCount1, sVersion in pairs(sVersions) do    

    -- Try opening the registry key
    sSubKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\"..sVersion..
              "\\Excel\\Options\\"
    sValues = Registry.GetValueNames(2, sSubKey);

    --initialize index counter
    iIndex = -2
    if sValues then

        --Determine the index of the maximimum OPEN registry entry
        --Next line has SetupFactory 8 code
        --for iCount2, sValue in sValues do
        for iCount2, sValue in pairs(sValues) do

            if (String.Left(sValue, 4) == "OPEN") then            
                --Check whether the user did not already install
                --the same add-in to prevent errors when opening Excel
                sKeysValue = Registry.GetValue(2, sSubKey, sValue, true)  
                if String.Find(sKeysValue, SessionVar.Expand(
                              "%AddinFileName%"), 1, false) > 0 then
                    iIndex = -1
                    -- leave loop
                    break;
                else
                    if (sValue == "OPEN") then
                        iIndex = 0
                    else
                        iIndex = String.ToNumber(String.Mid(
                                 sValue, 5, String.Length(sValue)-4))
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;

        -- -1 means: This add-in is already installed; we're done
        if iIndex ~= -1 then        
            --Determine path based on variable "%AddinFileName%
            sAppPath = String.Char(34)..
                       SessionVar.Expand("%AppFolder%")..
                       "\\"..
                       SessionVar.Expand("%AddinFileName%")..
                       String.Char(34)

            -- -2 is the initialized value of the index counter
            if (iIndex == -2) then
                -- OPEN-key does not exist
                Registry.SetValue(2, sSubKey, "OPEN",
                                  sAppPath, REG_SZ)
            else
                Registry.SetValue(2, sSubKey, "OPEN"..(iIndex + 1),
                                  sAppPath, REG_SZ)
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve this problem. When doing excel installiation, we must use registry record.

```
result = Registry.SetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\Addins\\company" , "LoadBehavior" , "3" , REG_DWORD );
result = Registry.SetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\Addins\\company" ,"FriendlyName", "program name", REG_SZ);
result = Registry.SetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\Addins\\company" , "Description" , "program name" , REG_SZ );
result = Registry.SetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\Addins\\company" ,"Manifest", SessionVar.Expand("%AppFolder%\\myvtofile.vsto|vstolocal"), REG_SZ);
```

for add-in start when excel startup.

LoadBehavior key's value should be "3".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are building an Automation addin.
 If so you need to prefix the addin name with /A to tell Excel that its an automation addin. otherwise its expecting an XLL or an XLA or an XLAM